# OpenGL Tessellation makes point

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, tessellation

A little problem with my tessellation shader. I try to implement a simple tessellation shader but it only makes points.

Here's my vertex shader :

```
out vec4 ecPosition;
out vec3 ecNormal;    
void main( void )
{
    vec4 position = gl_Vertex;

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    ecPosition  = gl_ModelViewMatrix * position;
    ecNormal    = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
}
```

My tessellation control shader :

```
layout(vertices = 3) out;
out vec4 ecPosition3[];
in vec3 ecNormal[];
in vec4 ecPosition[];
out vec3 myNormal[];
void main()
{
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position =  gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;
    myNormal[gl_InvocationID] = ecNormal[gl_InvocationID];
    ecPosition3[gl_InvocationID] = ecPosition[gl_InvocationID];
    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = float(4.0);
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = float(4.0);
    gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = float(4.0);
    gl_TessLevelInner[0] = float(4.0);
}
```

And my Tessellation Evaluation shader:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;
in vec3 myNormal[];
in vec4 ecPosition3[];
out vec3 ecNormal;
out vec4 ecPosition;

void main()
{
    float u = gl_TessCoord.x;                               
    float v = gl_TessCoord.y;                               
    float w = gl_TessCoord.z;                               
    vec3 position = vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz * u +     
                 gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz * v +     
                 gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz * w );    
    vec3 position2 = vec4(ecPosition3[0].xyz * u +          
                  ecPosition3[1].xyz * v +          
                  ecPosition3[2].xyz * w );         
    vec3 normal = myNormal[0] * u +                         
              myNormal[1] * v +                         
              myNormal[2] * w );                        
    ecNormal = normal;                          
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);                      
    ecPosition = vec4(position2, 1.0);                      
}
```

A screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This came up as recently active but doesn't appear to have been recently active. I can't tell what the shape in the screenshot is, but I'm assuming it looks enough like whatever the OP expected for him to conclude that everything is 99% working. The one thing I noticed is that the tessellator is outputting counter-clockwise triangles. I don't know if that's normal for openGL or not, but it's plausible that the screenshot is showing (and incorrectly lighting) faces that should have been culled. Was this already fixed in the last 4 years??

Answer (score 1):

You're only emitting one vertex. ;)

Here's how you should rewrite your geometry shader:

```
layout(vertices = 3) out;
out vec4 ecPosition3[];
in vec3 ecNormal[];
in vec4 ecPosition[];
out vec3 myNormal[];
void main()
{
    for (int p = 0; p < gl_in.length(); p++)
    {
        gl_Position =  gl_in[p].gl_Position;
        myNormal = ecNormal[p];
        ecPosition3 = ecPosition[p];
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = float(4.0);
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = float(4.0);
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = float(4.0);
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = float(4.0);

        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Note: this may still not be exactly what you want, but at least you'll be getting triangles as output.

Comment: Sorry same result :( . Look my screenshot : [link](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/9712/sanstitrektht.png)

Comment: He doesn't *have* a geometry shader. That's a tessellation evaluation shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well now I just feel silly. :( You're right, I've never worked with tessellation shaders before and I assumed it was a geometry shader by a different name.

Comment: Hmm, you are writing into gl_Position already transformed vertices. have you tried instead to do next in vertex shader gl_Position = gl_Vertex (or add another out variable like you did e.g. for normals). And then in tessellation evaluation shader actually write gl_Position = MVP * position